# Google Sheets - Autofill a cell within a certain column when a new Form is submitted

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm trying to have a cell auto-update so it can apply conditional formatting but the way Forms submits to a linked Sheet via making a new row is really messing with it. I've been trying to use an array formula but it just seems a little off from working and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

The formula I have now:
​=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(ROW(A:A)=1,"Replaced?",A:A="","",TRUE,K:K="N"))

What I want it to accomplish:
When a new Form is submitted, I want the new cell in column K to update with the letter N, and hopefully that triggers my conditional formatting to update the row as well. The cell in K1 needs to be named "Replaced?" and that seems to work fine for now.

Comment: Yeah I never use array formulas with google apps script.  They don't get along well.  I would have left the linked sheet alone to collect data and I would have constructed another sheet with onFormSubmit triggered function.  But either way google apps script and arrayformulas don't get along with each other.

Comment: @Cooper I'm hoping to avoid app script altogether if possible, right now it's all formulas and I dont *think* i need a script but i dunno. I removed the app script tag just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `Cell K1`:

```
={"Replaced?";index(if(len(indirect("A2:A")),"N",))}
```

Comment: That works great but I found a new issue that maybe I should have seen coming and planned ahead for it in the post:

When i change any of the N's in the K column to a Y (it's basically a yes or no column), it breaks the entire thing :( I was hoping there was a way for me to be able to place a Y and it carries on making the Ns afterwards either way.